# How to transpose column to rows?

Tags: excel, transpose

I have something like this:

```
hello
hi
how 
are 
you
hello
how
are
you
hello
hi
hi
hi
hello
hi
how
how 
are
hello
you
```

I want this column to transpose into rows like this:

```
hello hi how are you
hello how are you
hello hi hi hi
hello hi how how are
hello you
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks Carpetsmoker for editing the question u were faster than me. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve this riddle the VBA way then you might want to consider using this piece of code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()

Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
Dim DestinationRow As Long, DestinationColumn As Long

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SourceSheetName")
Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Before:=wsSource)

LastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

DestinationRow = 1
DestinationColumn = 1
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If LCase(Trim(wsSource.Cells(i, 1).Value2)) = "hello" Then
        DestinationColumn = 1
        DestinationRow = DestinationRow + 1
    Else
        DestinationColumn = DestinationColumn + 1
    End If
    wsDestination.Cells(DestinationRow, DestinationColumn).Value2 = wsSource.Cells(i, 1).Value2
Next i

End Sub
```

Obviously, you'll have to change in the above code `SourceSheetName` for the actual name of the sheet where the data resides. Other than that the code should work and do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

1) Select the data.
2) copy (Ctrl-c)
3) select the cell where you want to paste the transposed data.
4) paste special (under the edit menu or on the left side of the toolbar) and chose paste TRANSPOSE.

Comment: Hi Luke. I hope it was that easy. But I have 77,808 cells in that column. I need to create a formula that finds each cell that has "hello" in it and creates a row from there until it finds next cell containing "hello" and so on

Answer (score 0):

One way (probably not the best!) would be to terminate your list with `hello` then, assuming your first `hello` is in A2, in B2:

```
=IF(AND($A2="hello",COLUMN()<MATCH("hello",$A3:$A77809,0)+1),OFFSET($A2,COLUMN()-1,,),"")
```

Drag across and down until at least one column is entirely blank. Then select all, Copy, Paste Special..., Values and delete rows that are blank in ColumnB. Finally, if required, concatenate the pieces (cells) row by row with blanks in between each cell, repeat Paste/Special and delete surplus.

Answer (score 0):

With 78,000+ rows, the following VBA routine, using VBA arrays and a collection object should run fairly quickly, and more quickly than doing the "work" on the worksheet directly.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub HelloStart()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim COL As Collection
    Dim MaxCols As Long
    Dim V As Variant, W As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long


Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

Set COL = New Collection
For Each W In vSrc
    Select Case W
        Case Is = "Hello"
            If Not IsEmpty(V) Then
                COL.Add V
                MaxCols = IIf(MaxCols > UBound(V), MaxCols, UBound(V))
            End If
            ReDim V(1 To 1)
            V(1) = W
        Case Else
            ReDim Preserve V(1 To UBound(V) + 1)
            V(UBound(V)) = W
    End Select
Next W
If Not IsEmpty(V) Then COL.Add V
MaxCols = IIf(MaxCols > UBound(V), MaxCols, UBound(V))

ReDim vRes(1 To COL.Count, 1 To MaxCols)
I = 0
For Each V In COL
    I = I + 1
    J = 0
    For Each W In V
        J = J + 1
        vRes(I, J) = W
    Next W
Next V

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
wsRes.Cells.Clear
With rRes
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```